# Mongoose $push replacing whole array with a new array of one element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, updates, mongoose-schema

As per the title, I have an attribute `books` defined as

```
books: [{
  ref: 'Book',
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
}]
```

and I'm trying to update it with

```
await MyModel.updateOne({ id: myId }, { $push: { books: book._id } })
```

but every time the above update is called, the whole array is replaced with an array of one element (with "element" being the last pushed one). Hence I end up having something like

```
"books": [
    {
        "$oid": "5b47aa8ae2d927da983733cb"
    }
]
```

with always just one element.

This is happening running on

- node 8.10
- mongoose 5.14

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please try with update once `MyModel.update({ id: myId }, { $push: { books: book._id } })` if doesn't work then please post your full code

Comment: It worked, thanks! Is there any specific reason? Move your comment to answer and I'll mark it as solved. Thanks again.

Comment: No Idea!!! I have never used `updateOne` but do use `update` and that's why I suggested you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with update

```
MyModel.update({ id: myId }, { $push: { books: book._id } })
```